# Finding intersection of linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I know my naming is not good. Please exclude variable / function renaming reviews from your comments.

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;


/**
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216666/finding-the-intersecting-node-from-two-intersecting-linked-lists
 */
public class Interserction {

    private Node first;
    private Node last;
    private int size;

    public void add (int element) {
        final Node l = last;
        final Node newNode = new Node(element, null);
        last = newNode;
        if (first == null) {
            first = newNode;
        } else {
            l.next = newNode;
        }
        size++;
    }

    public void attach (Interserction l, int item) {
        if (l == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("The input linkedlist is null.");
        }
        if (l.last == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("The last element of linkedlist is null");
        }
        if (first == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("The linked list is empty.");
        }

        Node temp = first;
        int ctr = 0;
        while (temp != null) {
            if (temp.item == item) {
               l.last.next = temp;
               l.last = last;
               l.size = l.size + (size - ctr); // ------> Will need to deep dive this a bit.
               return;
            }
            temp = temp.next;
            ctr++;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The input item is invalid.");
    }

    public void displayList() {
        Node tempFirst = first;
        while (tempFirst != null) {
            System.out.print(tempFirst.item + " ");
            tempFirst = tempFirst.next;
        }
    }

    private static class Node {
        int item;
        Node next;

        Node(int element, Node next) {
            this.item = element;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    private Node hop(Interserction l, int hop) {
        assert l != null;
        assert l.first != null;

        Node temp = l.first;
        int counter = 0;
        while (counter < hop) {
            temp = temp.next;
            counter++;
        }
        return temp;
    }

    private Node getIntersectionNode(Node node1, Node node2) {
        assert node1 != null;
        assert node2 != null;

        while (node1 != node2) {
            node1 = node1.next;
            node2 = node2.next;
        }
        return node1;
    }

    private void verify(Interserction l) {
        if (l == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("The input is null");
        }
        if (last == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("this object has null node");
        }
        if (l.last == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("The input object has null node");
        }
    }

    public boolean doesIntersect(Interserction l) {
        verify(l);
        return last == l.last;
    }

    /**
     * Similar to String.compareTo line 1137.
     * Not using a function to get size for l.
     * this is again similar to anotherString.value.length in compareToFunction
     */
    public int findIntersectionItem(Interserction l) {
        verify(l);

        /**
         * QQ: calling doesIntersect:
         * pro: code duplication prevented, eg: last == l.last is not seen in 2 places
         * con: exception check is redundant. 
         * Whats the right thing.
         * 
         */
        if (!doesIntersect(l)) {
            /**
             * QQ: Verify this patten of state check function doesIntersect followed by an exception.
             */
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input linkedlist does not intersect.");
        }

        Node intersect;

        // guard clause just dint feel correct here.
        if (l.size > size) {
           Node begin = hop(l, l.size - size);
           intersect = getIntersectionNode(first, begin);
        } else {
           Node begin = hop(this, size - l.size);
           intersect = getIntersectionNode(begin, l.first);
        }

        // preferred single point of return.
        return intersect.item;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Interserction i1 = new Interserction();
        int[] l1 = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60};
        for (int i : l1) {
            i1.add(i);
        }

        Interserction i2 = new Interserction();
        int[] l2 = {17, 18};
        for (int i : l2) {
           i2.add(i);
        }

        i1.attach(i2, 30);

        // testing same length.
        System.out.println("Expted true, Actual: " + i1.doesIntersect(i2));
        System.out.println("Expected 30, Actual: " +  i1.findIntersectionItem(i2));

        i1.displayList();
        System.out.println();
        i2.displayList();
        System.out.println();

        Interserction i3 = new Interserction();
        int[] l3 = {18};
        for (int i : l3) {
           i3.add(i);
        }

        i1.attach(i3, 30);

        // testing same length.
        System.out.println("Expted true, Actual: " + i1.doesIntersect(i2));
        System.out.println("Expected 30, Actual: " +  i1.findIntersectionItem(i3));

        i1.displayList();
        System.out.println();
        i3.displayList();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest defining `getIntersectionNode()` right after `findIntersectionItem()`.  Also, put a comment there saying that `getIntersectionNode()` only works when the two arms of the "Y" are the same length (which is OK because only `findIntersectionItem()` calls it responsibly).

The first few lines of `attach()` can just call `verify()`.

Most of your `while` loops would be better written as `for` loops, since `for` loops are more compact and provide an easily recognizable structure to anyone reading the code.